# Reason for choice of the word "asymptotically" stable in Lyapunov stability theory?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definition, control-theory, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

The equilibrium $x^\ast$ is (Lyapunov) stable iff $$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \; \exists \delta(\varepsilon) : \lvert x(0) - x^\ast \rvert < \delta(\varepsilon) \Rightarrow \forall t \geqslant 0 \; \lvert x(t) - x^\ast \rvert < \varepsilon. $$

And equilibrium $x^\ast$ is asymptotically (Lyapunov) stable iff it's (Lyapunov) stable and every trajectory $x(t)$ from some neighbourhood tends to $x^\ast$ (i.e., $x(t) \rightarrow x^\ast$ when $t \rightarrow +\infty$)

Can someone explain to me why the choice of the word "asymptotic"?

Does it simply describe that the trajectory will converge to $x^\star$ but will not achieve it in finite time? (I am not totally sure if this is true for all dynamical systems)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assymptotically stable does indeed mean that a solutions assymptotically convergences to the equilibrium point. However this does not mean that it has to happen in infinite time. Namely if $x(\tau)=x^*$ for some finite $\tau$ then it still satisfies the limit that $x(t) \to x^*$ as $t \to \infty$, because $x(t)$ should remain equal to $x^*$ for all $t\geq\tau$.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a linear dynamical system (or perhaps nonlinear) that exhibits finite time convergence? I'm sure it happens for nonlinear systems, but for linear systems, solution are exponential, which indicates convergence only at infinite time? I think no linear dynamical system except for $\dot x = 0$ converges to equilibria at finite time.

Comment: @Themanofyourdream For continuous LTI systems you do indeed not have finite time convergence (maybe you could consider a pure time delay as a system with finite time convergence). Actually if such a system is assymptotically stable it is also exponentially stable, but indeed convergences in infinite time. But discrete LTI systems can most definitely have a finite time convergence. For nonlinear or time varying systems you could consider finite horizon LQR or Pontryagin's minimum principle as examples for finite time convergence.